# The maximal normal subgroup in U(n) and SU(n)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

Let $U(n)$ be a the unitary group the quotient $$\frac{U(n)}{U(n-1)} \simeq S^{2n-1}$$ and I believe that 
$$\frac{SU(n)}{SU(n-1)} \simeq S^{2n-1}.$$

Obviously the $U(n-1)$ is not a normal subgroup of $U(n)$. The $SU(n-1)$ is not a normal subgroup of $SU(n)$.

- What are the maximal normal subgroups in $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$ respectively?
- Write the maximal normal subgroups in $U(n)$ as $G_{U(n)}$, then what is the quotient group $U(n)/G_{U(n)}=$?
- Write the maximal normal subgroups in $SU(n)$ as $G_{SU(n)}$, then what is the quotient group $SU(n)/G_{SU(n)}=$?

Comment: In both cases, these are subgroups consisting of scalar matrices (assuming $n\ge 2$).

Comment: thanks what are formal ways to say maximal normal subgroups? and what are their quotient groups?